# Nodejs Sequelize ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

Tags: mysql, node.js, apache, phpmyadmin, sequelize.js

Залил сайт на node на Apache сервер и по какой-то причине вместо 'localhost" вписывает 127.0.0.1 и поэтому не получается подключиться к mysql бд. В документации sequelize также указывается хост, но у меня почему-то он меняется. Как исправить данную ошибку?

db.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    'manu',
    'manu',
    'Pass404NotFound',
    {
        host: "localhost",
        dialect: 'mysql',
        timezone: '+03:00',
    }
)


module.exports = sequelize
```

app.js

```
sequelize.sync()
    .then(() => {
        app.listen(8080)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

error.log

```
App 12906 output: ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
App 12906 output:     at ConnectionManager.connect (/home/siusqmjo/nodevenv/node/8/lib/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:116:17)
App 12906 output:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
App 12906 output:   parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
App 12906 output:       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16) {
App 12906 output:     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
App 12906 output:     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
App 12906 output:     syscall: 'connect',
App 12906 output:     address: '127.0.0.1',
App 12906 output:     port: 3306,
App 12906 output:     fatal: true
App 12906 output:   },
App 12906 output:   original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
App 12906 output:       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16) {
App 12906 output:     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
App 12906 output:     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
App 12906 output:     syscall: 'connect',
App 12906 output:     address: '127.0.0.1',
App 12906 output:     port: 3306,
App 12906 output:     fatal: true
App 12906 output:   }
App 12906 output: }
```

Comment: _вместо 'localhost" вписывает 127.0.0.1 и поэтому не получается подключиться_ - не поэтому.

Comment: С тех поддержкой хостинга разобраться пытались. Они тоже говорят, что никаких проблем нет, единственное host должен быть указан localhost, чтобы получилось подключаться к mysql.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - это и есть localhost.

Comment: я бы с консоли попытался бы подключится. или хотя бы проверил, а открыт ли порт 3306.

Comment: Я в этом же хостинге подключаюсь к той же бд через php без проблем, но на node Sequelize выдает такую ошибку..